# Distinguish between Records and Objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a conditional type in TypeScript that distinguishes between "record" types (where keys are unbounded/dynamic) and plain object types (where keys are pre-defined).

```
type R = { [x: string]: any }
type O = { a: string; b: number }
```

I can get the keys of the types and check for some hopefully-sure-to-not-exist property:

```
type R = { [x: string]: any }
type O = { a: string; b: number }

type IsRecord<T> = '__NEVER__' extends keyof T ? true : false

type RR = IsRecord<R> // true
type OO = IsRecord<O> // false
```

But this feels hacky. Is this possible in a cleaner way?

Comment: Is the ternary in `'__NEVER__' extends keyof R ? true : false` necessary? If `'__NEVER__' extends keyof R` returns a `boolean`, it is redundant.

Comment: You could alternatively use `!!('__NEVER__' extends keyof O)`

Comment: @AlexH in the case of conditional types I believe it is necessary. But that was only pseudocode, I've edited the example to make it slightly more clear hopefully. I'm looking for an answer that doesn't involve the `__NEVER__` fake key test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `string`-[indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) can be identified by checking whether `string` itself is one of its keys:

```
type IsRecord<T> = string extends keyof T ? true : false

type RR = IsRecord<R> // true
type OO = IsRecord<O> // false
```

Yes, you can do it the way you've been doing with a fake key, but if you're worried about "hackiness" I'd suggest using `string` instead.

Note that there are also `number`-indexable types (like `Array<any>`), and since `string` is not necessarily a key of a `number`-indexed type, these will show up as non-record:

```
type N = { [x: number]: any };
type NN = IsRecord<N>; // false
```

If you need to identify both `string` and `number` indexes as record-like, it suffices to check for `number`, since *from the point of view of keys*, `number` is assignable to  `string`.  (This might be confusing, but since all JS objects actually use `string` or `symbol` keys, whenever you index into an object with a `number`, it gets coerced to a `string` first.  `arr[0]` and `arr["0"]` are the same thing.  TypeScript supports this by treating all `string`-indexed types as having both `string` and `number` as its keys.  The above link goes over this):

```
type IsNumericIndex<T> = number extends keyof T ? true : false

type RRR = IsNumericIndex<R> // true
type OOO = IsNumericIndex<O> // false
type NNN = IsNumericIndex<N> // true
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASlC8UDeUDaAPAXFAzsATgJYB2A5gLrYCGxIUAvgFCiRQDyCyUV2eRZAbigAjbMQCuAW2ER8DRs3DQAkjhgQAxgHt8AEwA8AFQB8nPiVJQI6YBGK6cUANYQQWgGZRDUAPxQC4tDY7lQANjgQCizQMHCIquraevowpgD0af74gYqsbBzxapo6BmzpmSHhkbnQAHKcKBhiUjL4lNy0DAI1ULX1hYkl+rXGQhlQlRFRSlCqtVKyhBrK9tZGpogS0rJWNnYOzq4eXr5ZgVDBYVM9sXGzOPOSi8ur6CnlZ5HR7PmccwtEF66NZlKDjSZfGZ9fr3R7PFbAt4jMGZAKRIA)

Comment: Wow, so simple yet I didn't think of it. Thank you!